# C# - Incoming <form> POST not hitting page in ASPX, only the GET on redirect

Tags: c#

I am trying to accept a POST request from a  action.

When an external site (Example code below) sends a  request using a POST method, The POST is not picked up by my System.Web.UI.Page and my debug is only hit once the user is redirected and there is a GET request.

External Site Example Code (This was provided to me by a PaymentProvider to show how they will be posting a response to a provided URL):

```
    <html>
   <head>
      <title>Example</title>
   </head>
   <body OnLoad="OnLoadEvent();"> 
      <br/>
      <form name="theForm" method="POST" 
         action="http://localhost:64867.../Payment3DSConfirmation.aspx">
         <input type="hidden" name="Test1" value="Test1Data"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="Test2" value="Test2Data"/>
         <input type="submit" name="Continue"/>
      </form>
      <script language="Javascript"> 
         function OnLoadEvent() {
         // Make the form post as soon as it has been loaded.
         document.theForm.submit();
         } 
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

My ASPX.cs Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Test.Interface.Payment
{
    public partial class Payment3DSConfirmation : System.Web.UI.Page
    { 
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
            for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
            {
                Response.Write(keys[i] + ": " + Request.Form[keys[i]] + "<br>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using the above in my code behind, and making a POST request (using the External Site Example Code.) the Request.Forms.AllKeys is empty, I also logged the Request.HttpMethod to a text file and I didn't log any post request apart from when I send a POST request from POSTMAN.

If I send the individual POST request in POSTMAN then it is picked up by the Page_Load but if I POST to it using the External Site Example Code, only a GET request is processed.

Comment: If you load the html page, you don't get `Test1: Test1Data Test2: Test2Data` printed to the page? Have you removed the comments in the javascript? The `<!--` and `// -->` before and after the OnLoadEvent()?

Comment: I have removed the `<!--` and `// -->` before and after the OnLoadEvent(). No I do not get the expected results of `Test1: Test1Data Test2: Test2Data`. When I place a debug, I can see that the List Request.Forms.AllKeys is empty.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code as posted. Are they typos?

- The form's opening tag isn't closed with a '>', and
- the javascript is commented out with html comments. get rid of those.

I tried what you have with those fixed and it works.

```
<body OnLoad="OnLoadEvent();"> 
  <br/>
  <form name="theForm" method="POST" 
     action="http://localhost:64867.../Payment3DSConfirmation.aspx">
     <input type="hidden" name="Test1" value="Test1Data"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="Test2" value="Test2Data"/>
     <input type="submit" name="Continue"/>
  </form>
  <script>
     function OnLoadEvent() {
         // Make the form post as soon as it has been loaded.
         document.theForm.submit();
     }
  </script>
</body>
```

Code behind:

```
string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
{
    Response.Write(keys[i] + ": " + Request.Form[keys[i]] + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: I will clarify this in my question, The example external site code is what was provided to me by a PaymentProvider to show how they will be posting a response to a provided URL.

Your updated code didn't solve the issue, I changed the code, directing it to my site and I still only receive the GET request.

Comment: I added some code behind to show how I'm reading posted data. Can you update your question to show how you are determining that you are not getting a POST and only a GET. I don't understand.

Comment: i have updated my question with more information.